# Accessing the household_object_database remotely from willowgarage - server down?

Tags: ros, household-objects-database

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I was trying to use the household_object_database remotely from willow garage using [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/household_objects_database/Tutorials/Use%20the%20household_objects_database%20remotely%20from%20a%20Willow%20Garage%20server)
and got the error

```
ERROR: Unable to communicate with service [/objects_database_node/get_model_list], address [rosrpc://grasp.willowgarage.com:15432]
```

rather than the below one mentioned in the tutorial.

```
ERROR: Unable to communicate with service [/objects_database_node/get_model_description], address [rosrpc://grasp.willowgarage.com:15432]
```

Is it because of the server down issues or am i missing something here.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12610/accessing-the-household_object_database-remotely-from-willowgarage---server-down?/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2012-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ["Is it up?" site](http://www.isup.me) says `grasp.willowgarage.com` is down right now.

That is a good way to check on things like this.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-01-13**:
I suppose you can wait until it's back up, then make your own local copy.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-01-13**:
So how do i solve this? Am i supposed to wait for someone to restart the server or stop using this package?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you only need the models you may get them from here:

http://vault.willowgarage.com/wgdata1/vol1/model_database/

Otherwise wait, they normally restart the server on the same day.

D.

---

Originally posted by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) with karma: 1420 on 2012-01-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-01-13**:
how do i change the link here. I mean to the server you mentioned here.

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2012-10-28**:
Hi @dejanpan! I'm connecting to the database recently (10 Oct 2012) and for a few days, it has not connected successfully. Is it correct to download from this link https://code.ros.org/svn/data/trunk/household_objects/ instead of one you suggested? I think I should use offline database now

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2013-03-12**:
@dejanpan
what should I do after downloading the models from:
http://vault.willowgarage.com/wgdata1/vol1/model_database/ , as I have the same problem ..

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately, we are no longer supporting remote access to a database server hosted at Willow Garage. Instructions for installing the household_objects_databaselocally  are provided here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/household_objects_database

---

Originally posted by [Matei Ciocarlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/36/matei-ciocarlie/) with karma: 586 on 2013-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1